# Is there a way to re-organize the way mailboxes from multiple accounts are organized in macOS Mail?

Tags: macos, mail.app, email

I am trying to group the folders by email account not by type, if I have three mail accounts:

- Gmail,
- Outlook,
- iCloud.

I want them to be shown in the Mail app, as follow:

```
- Gmail
    - Inbox
    - Received
    - Junk
    etc…
```

But the way it’s shown as follow

```
Inbox
- Gmail
- Outlook
- iCloud
```

Is there any way I can do this with the Mail app in macOS?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an image of my set up before posting this answer:
[image]

Now if I make the following three changes (one pop-up kept to show what to choose, on the left of the preference pane is the result in the mailbox display:
[image]